# CakePHP: Unable to load behavior settings from plugin

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to pass settings to a behavior, which is provided by the [cakephp-file-storage-plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage). However, the settings are not being recognized. For example, if I try to exclude GIF files by leaving them out of the array,I can still upload them without error. With logging, I can confirm that the behavior is being attached to the model, but when I log the settings they are empty. I know the plugin/behavior works, but unfortunately there is very little documentation for the plugin/behavior, so I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Below is my model code, where I pass the settings via `$actsAs` as well as the complete behavior file, which I've added logging to in an attempt to figure out why the settings aren't working. The output of that logging is included below. `ListingPhoto` is aliased as `Photo`, as a hasMany association of another class, which is why that name appears in the debug output. But I can't fully explain why the behavior code seems to run so many times for one single request.

My model:

```
<?php

App::uses('ImageStorage', 'FileStorage.Model');
class ListingPhoto extends ImageStorage {

    public $name = 'ListingPhoto';

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Imagine.Imagine',
        'FileStorage.UploadValidator' => array(
            'localFile' => true,
            'validate' => false,
            'allowedExtensions' => array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png')
        ),
    );

    public function upload($listing_id, $data) {
        $data[$this->alias]['adapter'] = 'Local';
        $data[$this->alias]['model'] = 'ListingPhoto'; 
        $data[$this->alias]['foreign_key'] = $listing_id;
        $this->create();
        return $this->save($data);

    }

    public function afterDelete() {
        parent::afterDelete();
        $this->log($this->record);
        StorageManager::adapter($this->record['Photo']['adapter'])->delete($this->record['Photo']['path']);

    }

}
```

The complete behavior file, with my logging added:

```
<?php
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
App::uses('CakeNumber', 'Utility');

/**
 * Upload Validation Behavior
 *
 * This behavior will validate uploaded files, nothing more, it won't take care of storage.
 *
 * @author Florian Krämer
 * @copyright 2012 Florian Krämer
 * @license MIT
 */
class UploadValidatorBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

/**
 * Settings array
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $settings = array();

/**
 * Default settings array
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $_defaults = array(
        'fileField' => 'file',
        'validate' => true,
        'allowNoFileError' => true,
        'allowedMime' => null,
        'allowedExtensions' => null,
        'localFile' => false
    );

/**
 * Error message
 *
 * If something fails this is populated with an error message that can be passed to the view
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $uploadError = null;

/**
 * Behavior setup
 *
 * Merge settings with default config, then it is checking if the target directory
 * exists and if it is writeable. It will throw an error if one of both fails.
 *
 * @param \AppModel|\Model $Model
 * @param array $settings
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 * @return void
 */
    public function setup(Model $Model, $settings = array()) {
        if (!is_array($settings)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(__d('file_storage', 'Settings must be passed as array!'));
        }
        $this->log("SETTINGS for {$Model->alias}:");
        $this->log($settings);
        // $this->settings[$Model->alias] = array_merge($this->_defaults, $settings);
    }

/**
 * Before validation callback
 *
 * Check if the file is really an uploaded file and run custom checks for file 
 * extensions and / or mime type if configured to do so.
 *
 * @param Model $Model
 * @param array $options
 * @return boolean True on success
 */
    public function beforeValidate(Model $Model, $options = array()) {

        $this->log('beforeValidate...');

        $this->log('options');
        $this->log( $options );

        $this->log('$this->settings[$Model->alias]');
        $this->log($this->settings[$Model->alias]);

        $this->log('$this->settings');
        $this->log($this->settings);

        extract($this->settings[$Model->alias]);

        $this->log('$validate');
        $this->log($validate);

        if ($validate === true && isset($Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField]) && is_array($Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField])) {

            if ($Model->validateUploadError($Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField]['error']) === false) {
                $Model->validationErrors[$fileField] = array($this->uploadError);
                return false;
            }

            if (!empty($Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField])) {
                if (empty($localFile) && !is_uploaded_file($Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField]['tmp_name'])) {
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'The uploaded file is no valid upload.');
                    $Model->invalidate($fileField, $this->uploadError);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (is_array($allowedMime)) {
                if (!$this->validateAllowedMimeTypes($Model, $allowedMime)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            $this->log('allowedExtensions');
            $this->log($allowedExtensions);
            if (is_array($allowedExtensions)) {
                if (!$this->validateUploadExtension($Model, $allowedExtensions)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Validates the extension
 *
 * @param Model $Model
 * @param $validExtensions
 * @return boolean True if the extension is allowed
 */
    public function validateUploadExtension(Model $Model, $validExtensions) {
        $this->log('validateUploadExtension');
        extract($this->settings[$Model->alias]);
        $extension = $this->fileExtension($Model, $Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField]['name'], false);

        if (!in_array(strtolower($extension), $validExtensions)) {
            $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'You are not allowed to upload files of this type.');
            $Model->invalidate($fileField, $this->uploadError);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Validates if the mime type of an uploaded file is allowed
 *
 * @param Model $Model
 * @param array Array of allowed mime types
 * @return boolean
 */
    public function validateAllowedMimeTypes(Model $Model, $mimeTypes = array()) {
        extract($this->settings[$Model->alias]);
        if (!empty($mimeTypes)) {
            $allowedMime = $mimeTypes;
        }

        $File = new File($Model->data[$Model->alias][$fileField]['tmp_name']);
        $mimeType = $File->mime();

        if (!in_array($mimeType, $allowedMime)) {
            $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'You are not allowed to upload files of this type.');
            $Model->invalidate($fileField, $this->uploadError);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Valdates the error value that comes with the file input file
 *
 * @param Model $Model
 * @param integer Error value from the form input [file_field][error]
 * @return boolean True on success, if false the error message is set to the models field and also set in $this->uploadError
 */
    public function validateUploadError(Model $Model, $error = null) {
        if (!is_null($error)) {
            switch ($error) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                    return true;
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'The uploaded file exceeds limit of %s.', CakeNumber::toReadableSize(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')));
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'The uploaded file is to big, please choose a smaller file or try to compress it.');
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.');
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    if ($this->settings[$Model->alias]['allowNoFileError'] === false) {
                        $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'No file was uploaded.');
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'The remote server has no temporary folder for file uploads. Please contact the site admin.');
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'Failed to write file to disk. Please contact the site admin.');
                break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'File upload stopped by extension. Please contact the site admin.');
                break;
                default:
                    $this->uploadError = __d('file_storage', 'Unknown File Error. Please contact the site admin.');
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Returns the latest error message
 *
 * @param \AppModel|\Model $Model
 * @return string
 * @access public
 */
    public function uploadError(Model $Model) {
        return $this->uploadError;
    }

/**
 * Returns an array that matches the structure of a regular upload for a local file
 *
 * @param Model $Model
 * @param $file
 * @param string File with path
 * @return array Array that matches the structure of a regular upload
 */
    public function uploadArray(Model $Model, $file, $filename = null) {
        $File = new File($file);

        if (empty($fileName)) {
            $filename = basename($file);
        }

        return array(
            'name' => $filename,
            'tmp_name' => $file,
            'error' => 0,
            'type' => $File->mime(),
            'size' => $File->size());
    }

/**
 * Return file extension from a given filename
 *
 * @param Model $Model
 * @param $name
 * @param bool $realFile
 * @internal param $string
 * @return boolean string or false
 */
    public function fileExtension(Model $Model, $name, $realFile = true) {
        if ($realFile) {
            return pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }
        return substr(strrchr($name,'.'), 1);
    }

}
```

The output of my logging:

```
2014-12-23 20:04:32 Error: SETTINGS for ImageStorage:
2014-12-23 20:04:32 Error: Array
(
    [localFile] => 1
    [validate] => 
    [allowedExtensions] => Array
        (
            [0] => jpg
            [1] => jpeg
            [2] => png
            [3] => gif
        )

)

2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: SETTINGS for Photo:
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: Array
(
    [localFile] => 1
    [validate] => 
    [allowedExtensions] => Array
        (
            [0] => jpg
            [1] => jpeg
            [2] => png
            [3] => gif
            [4] => jpg
            [5] => png
            [6] => xxx
        )

)

2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: beforeValidate...
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: options
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: Array
(
    [validate] => 1
    [fieldList] => Array
        (
        )

    [callbacks] => 1
    [counterCache] => 1
)

2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: $this->settings[$Model->alias]
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: 
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: $this->settings
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: Array
(
    [priority] => 10
)

2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: $validate
2014-12-23 20:04:33 Error: 
2014-12-23 20:04:38 Error: SETTINGS for ImageStorage:
2014-12-23 20:04:38 Error: Array
(
    [localFile] => 1
    [validate] => 
    [allowedExtensions] => Array
        (
            [0] => jpg
            [1] => jpeg
            [2] => png
            [3] => gif
        )

)

2014-12-23 20:04:39 Error: SETTINGS for Photo:
2014-12-23 20:04:39 Error: Array
(
    [localFile] => 1
    [validate] => 
    [allowedExtensions] => Array
        (
            [0] => jpg
            [1] => jpeg
            [2] => png
            [3] => gif
            [4] => jpg
            [5] => png
            [6] => xxx
        )

)
```

**Update1**

I noticed in the log output that my settings seem to be getting added to the defaults, instead of replacing them:

```
2014-12-23 21:55:07 Error: SETTINGS for Photo:
2014-12-23 21:55:07 Error: Array
(
    [localFile] => 1
    [validate] => 
    [allowedExtensions] => Array
        (
            [0] => jpg
            [1] => jpeg
            [2] => png
            [3] => gif
            [4] => jpg   <--my addition
            [5] => png   <--my addition
            [6] => xxx   <--my addition
        )

)
```

Comment: Which branch of the plugin are you using? Also I don't get your issue, is the file upload not validated?

Comment: I'm on the master branch, after following the install instructions in the README.md. The issue is that I can only get the default settings to work. I can't choose my own valid extensions or file sizes. No matter what I set the defaultss are applied.

Comment: When you `extends` in PHP. It replaces properties and doesn't merge them. Is it possible that some of the settings from `ImageStorage.$actsAs` are required for this to work. I've never used the plugin. So I don't know, but you've removed the `Imagine.Imagine` behavior from the base model.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini That was a *great* thought. I totally missed that. But I tried it with the other behavior included and it still didn't recognize my settings. However, I did notice something... see my update above.

Comment: @SDP CakePHP could be the one doing this merge of the settings. When you define a model it will merge properties from your `AppModel`. Looks like it is using the base class instead of `AppModel`. It will only do this for the properties that CakePHP wants merged. This is all part of the wacky abstraction stuff in Cake.

Comment: Yea it's weird. @burzum says it's working in other projects. And there are some tests for the validation behavior which pass using non-default settings, but in the test they are loaded "on the fly". Not sure why that should matter.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an issue if my plugin. But the core class `Object::_mergeVars()`, the Model class inherits that. It merges the `$actsAs property` the way you get it.

There is no way I could fix this in my plugin other than that you use the already existing `configureUploadValidation()` method of the behavior. I'll add this as a note to the documentation of the plugin tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I actually already tried with the `name` property set, and it still didn't work. (I've updated the question with my *complete* model file)

Comment: BTW, I also tried removing the `$actsAs` completely and `load()`ing the behavior on the fly (as in the unit test), but same results. My next theory is that maybe the behavior is working differently because my model extends ImageStorage. I'm going to try with different ancestor and report back.

Comment: Try to reload the behavior before doing your save call. $this->Behaviors->load(...); this should re-new the configuration. You can also just call configureUploadValidation($options) on the extending model, see the FileStorage model, it implements this method.

Comment: I maybe figured it out: when change my model to inherit from AppModel instead of ImageStorage then my `$actsAs` settings seem to work!

Comment: About your last suggestion. I was testing by doing `unload()` followed by `load()` (with my custom settings) in the controller action. I didn't try the configureUploadValidation() yet but I will.

Comment: I changed the unit tests so that the TestModel inherits `$actsAs` settings that match ImageStorage (to simulate my situation) and they indeed fail. Do you want a PR with that test?

Comment: More good news! Your second suggestion (`configureUploadValidation()`) seems to work. Previously I was trying to (re)load the behavior settings form the controller. That's probably why it didn't work before.

Comment: Please tell me just the branch, I'll pull it in a separate branch myself and test it and see where the issue is before I merge it into develop.

Comment: Voila: https://github.com/s-d-p/cakephp-file-storage/tree/image-storage-unit-test

Comment: @SDP your test doesn't prove anything. All it does it loads different settings for the behavior and that the reason why the expectations fail. If your goal was to prove that the merging of the settings is not working, well you proved the opposite. You overwrite the `validate` setting of the behavior with false, default is true. That is the reason why the test fails after your change. I'm not going to merge these changes.

Comment: @SDP is your actual issue that it merges and does not replace the extensions array?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. If the model extends ImageStorage, then I am unable to exclude any of the default image extensions. For example, I want to block GIF files. But these are included in the defaults, so no matter what setting I pass to the behavior, GIFs are always allowed.

Comment: That's caused by the array merging. I need to look into this. You can simply to this as well as an intermediate workaround in your model: $this->Behaviors->UploadValidator->settings[$this->alias]['allowedExtensions'] = array(...); This should override it as well.

Comment: Right. That's all my test was attempting to demonstrate. Sorry for the confusion. Let me know if there's anything I can do to help.

Comment: @SDP That's not an issue if my plugin. But the core class `Object::_mergeVars()`, model inherits that. It merges the `$actsAs` property the way you get it. There is no way I could fix this in my plugin other than that you use the already existing `configureUploadValidation()` method. I'll add this as a note to the documentation tomorrow. I've updated my answer. By the way, this will happen with every model or controller you extend that uses _mergeVars()!

Comment: I understand the source of the problem is an interaction between CakePHP core and the plugin defaults. Would it make sense to remove the $actsAs from the ImageStorage class as a workaround? That way the inherited settings would not be "absorbed" by the merge.

Comment: @SDP No, this won't be a solution because it won't validate the file upload out of the box any more and on top it would be a backward compatibility breaking change. Just use the configureUploadValidation() method and you're OK. I might implement something like setExtensionsForValidation(). I never liked _mergeVars(), this is not the first time this is causing an issue.